# Drawing with transparency in opengl es 2

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm working on a simple drawing application. My line is constructed using polygons and things look good so far. I would like to add a transparency feature and I used `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` for that reason. However, because my polys sometimes overlap, I get the ugly result shown in the picture (multiple layers of transparency).  What I would like to get is the figure in the left(no overlapping because there is no transparency), with an overall transparency.

I guess I could do this by keeping the polys from overlaping, but that would be a overkill for this task I think. There should be a way to control them at drawing time, but being a beginner with OpenGL doesn't help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but the way transparency works does not allow you to do what you want without manually keeping the polygons from overlapping. The way that transparency works is that it takes the colour of the surface below it, and uses the blending function you specify in order to calculate the final colour of the pixel.

In your program you are drawing multiple polygons with alpha on top of each other. That means that their colours add up, giving the result you see.

I've never actually written a drawing application, but you could perhaps take a look at triangle strips to draw your lines. They allow you to extend the line point by point, and make sure the geometry won't overlap with itself.